# The change in the django view is not reflected to the page until restarting uwsgi

Tags: django, nginx, django-views, uwsgi

I installed `Django` + `Uwsgi` + `Nginx`.
Project is running. But when i change something in the `view`, the change is not reflected to page until i restart `uwsgi`. Should i restart `uwsgi` everytime i make a change in the `view`?
But when i add time to `view` to show in the page. The displayed time is changing everytime i refresh the page.

My `view` is :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse   # added
from django.utils import timezone
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('This is the home page. 101' + str(timezone.now()))
```

My `urls.py` :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from godentiapp import views    # added 

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),    # added
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),  
]
```

Comment: Yes, each time you change the source code, you need to restart the webserver, since the files are always loaded *once*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should [I] restart uwsgi everytime [I] make a change in the view?

**Yes**, each time you change the *source code*, you need to restart the webserver, since the files are always loaded *once*. The Python interpreter will read the source file, and load it in memory. Changes the the file will not be reflected.

If you work with Django in *development mode*, for modifications to the sourcde file it will [automatically *restart* the server <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver):

> The *development server* automatically reloads Python code for each request, as needed. You don’t need to restart the server for code changes to take effect. However, some actions like adding files don’t trigger a restart, so you’ll have to restart the server in these cases.

But this is thus not done in production, and should not be done, since this can result in security risks.